# Increase and decrease font size Buttons on Bootstrap 3 Framework

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have build a website using Bootstrap 3.
This i want now is 2 Buttons. One for increasing font-size of ALL elements of page and one for decreasing. (For persons with Disability)

I use this jquery script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Increase Font Size
  $(".increase").click(function(){
    var currentSize = $('*').css('font-size');
    var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*1.2;
    $('*').css('font-size', currentSize);

    return false;
  });

  // Decrease Font Size
  $(".decrease").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('*').css('font-size');
    var currentSize = $('*').css('font-size');
    var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*0.8;
    $('*').css('font-size', currentSize);

    return false;
  });
  });
```

But as i can see by using a sellect all *, the button first decrease and then increase or doing anything else.
Otherwise by using id name nothing happens.

```
  // Increase Font Size
  $(".increase").click(function(){
    var currentSize = $('#all-wrapper').css('font-size');
    var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*1.2;
    $('#all-wrapper').css('font-size', currentSize);

    return false;
  });
```

You can see 2 JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stefanos10G/3Gjkr/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stefanos10G/nb2B5/) . 
I'd appreciated if you can suggest me sth. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not increase the font-size in terms of multiplication as you are doing!
In first approach when you do

```
var currentFontSize = $('*').css('font-size');
```

it will take font size of the first selected element that is button and in next sentence will apply 1.2 times of the buttons font to each element. so it'f first decreases to button font-size and then increases.

while second approach works but font size of $('#all-wrapper') div is over ride for h1 tag so it's not visible.

To achieve the increase or decrease font functionality we normally switch the css with different font-size.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you give me an example (maybe a link) of switching the css with different font-size?

Comment: $(".btn").click(function (){
   $('link[href="style2.css"]').attr('href','style1.css');
});

Comment: Thanks.. I try to change first selected element's font size which is button for not having decrease at first increase click. Although i can change it... it seems that it doesnt change anything on increae behavior. For once again it decrease first. Can you help me with that?

Comment: what change did you make?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stefanos10G/3NgrM/ : Look at this Please... Although increase class font size changed, it still decrease first even increase button clicked.

Comment: When you are doing $("*") as per dom HTML is the first element which has font size of 10px; have a look http://jsfiddle.net/3NgrM/1/

Comment: Yes, i can see it by the console alert you've added but which is the first DOM element so i can change it? Even if i change the "html body font's size" the first font-size is still 10px...